# Should coding Q&A (what we think of as 'Stack Overflow' today) become a not for profit? Warning: contains positivity!

Tags: discussion

As a user who still regards themselves very much as a basic Stack Overflow user I've been watching the recent moderator issues and breakdown in trust between the community and the SE company with sadness and then with increasing alarm as I've begun to educate myself on what the 'community' actually does (turns out it's a lot and it's really important!).

Standing back from the recent events, it seems like there may always the potential for a conflict of interest between a company participating in a free market economy and a community's goals.  Ultimately the community wants the best possible set of questions and answers, whereas the company wants to achieve the best commercial performance.  Those two goals aren't necessarily mutually exclusive, but they aren't necessarily complementary either.

Now here's the positive bit - to me Stack Overflow (that's the SE site I use regularly) has literally been life changing, I started out as a Civil Engineer and then moved to software development and I could not have done that without Stack Overflow.

Indeed, every day my company, and probably every software company on earth, uses Stack Overflow to solve problems (and hopefully also to post solutions to them).  I imagine someone has already tried to work this out, but the value of Stack Overflow to the world economy must be colossal... I mean truly, staggeringly huge.  Think of the value of the tech-economy at this point and how quickly it's progressed - we, the Stack Overflow community, we are a big part of that progress.

To my mind, the continual growth of the high quality existing library of knowledge built initially here at Stack Overflow is simply too important for it to be risked by a conflict with commercial interests - it should be a world-owned resource rather than a commercial or national entity.

For that reason, it seems like the best approach might be to switch the location where this Q&A data is collected and maintained to somewhere operating with a not-for-profit model whereby the only goal for all parties is increasing the size of the library and maintaining its quality?

I've no idea how that would physically be achieved, and the NFP model has its own issues no doubt, but if there's going to be an exodus, perhaps we should be looking to the tech industry for donations to set up a coding foundation as a new home for Q&A?

**Clarification**
What I mean here, is not that the existing company should change its corporate structure to be a NFP (although that could work), but more that if people are going to form new Q&A sites (as appears to be starting to happen), then maybe it's time to rethink how those sites/this bank of knowledge is funded and managed going forward.

I'm trying to avoid drawing the comparison with Wikipedia, but the principle about making an important set of data available for careful curation is similar.

Comment: The company has gone through several rounds of funding. It's a bit too late to talk about this. The idea could be accomplished somewhere else, but not here.

Comment: The goals of commercial success and *"increasing the size of the library and maintaining its quality"* should really be the same thing. I'm not sure about the _main_ revenue stream of SE exactly, but surely having more eyes on the site must be a good thing. And you get eyes on the site if you have a *large, quality library* of good content. Optimising for any other metric should be counter productive, first qualitatively and subsequently eventually financially.

Comment: @yivi yes exactly so, somewhere else, that's what I meant in the last paragraph

Comment: @yivi: Are you alluding to codidact.org? :)

Comment: Well, maybe you should change your title, where you explicitly ask "should Stack Overflow become a non-profit"?

Comment: @yivi duly amended

Comment: @machine_1 Not necessarily, I haven't looked at that project very closely yet, and I'm yet a bit sceptical. Time will tell. Hopefully I'm wrong, and either that one or topanswers.xyz (or something else entirely) will prove to be what it's needed.

Comment: We've already pretty much reached the same strictness and consequent number of complaints as Wikipedia, so going the entire way towards a Wiki Overflow backed by a StackMedia Foundation only makes sense. ;)

Comment: I don't know, the question it's either about Stack Overflow, in which case it doesn't make a lot of sense, or it's about creating another entity unrelated with SO/SE...in which case is not on-topic? Sorry, I don't see the question working. My apologies if it's me the one failing to understand.

Comment: @yivi One could merge your two options if the 'assumed question' were to be rephrased to allude to a *comprehensive reassessment of the SE Inc. Board of Directors*?

Comment: @Adrian That question wouldn't make any sense. We do not discuss the company governance here.

Comment: @yivi Aah - sorry.

Comment: The Google search engine is very important to mankind too, since no matter what we think of that company, it is undeniably the best one around. Maybe we should propose to Google that they turn it open source and non-profit? P.S. I would also love to get my own live unicorn. Preferably a fluffy pink one, if possible.

Comment: Asking "should" is in my opinion too opinion-based. Rather ask "What would the advantages and disadvantage of X compared to Y be?" or "How could one transition from X to Y?", maybe also "Is X feasible?".

Comment: The question also conflates "should it be so?" with "should this particular group of people make it so?"

Comment: The answer to the second one is obviously "no", because why would you ever convert a for-profit company that is generating profit for you into a NFP? Especially one that's generating profit for *investors*. That part makes it illegal - I don't think you're allowed to deliberately deprive your investors of money.

Comment: @user253751 I'm sure that if we asked nicely they wouldn't mind. Investors are easy going as a rule. Also, we need to generate enough money in donations and what-not to support SO employees. Our target audience is **much** smaller thank Wikipedia.

Comment: @yivi: _"Hey investors, remember when you invested <large sum of cash> into this site? We want to make the site non-profit. You'll never get your cash back, but it's for a good cause! Those programmers need their answers!"_  Yea, that's not gonna be appreciated.

Comment: @Cerbrus Do you think they'll remember? Maybe they forgot. And it almost worked for WeWork... SO should have gone to SoftBank to ask for money.

Comment: @yivi I reckon it's worth a try. Let's get the new CEO right on that.

Comment: @yivi That's all sarcasm, right?

Comment: @user253751 Mostly tongue in cheek, yes. My avatar is a monkey, so it's safer not to take me too seriously. Although it **did** almost work for WeWork. But that's something entirely different...

Comment: *"the continual growth of the high quality existing library of knowledge built initially here at Stack Overflow"* ... you obviously don't spend much time on the [php] tag - most *high quality* questions there are duplicates, the rest is dross. The PHP language doesn't iterate rapidly enough to merit the number of questions asked on SO - and once you've got a nice stable library, where every sensible question has been asked, you spend most time asking for clarification in comments or DV/VTC. That might give you a high quality, moderated library but it's not going to draw in the ad revenue.

Comment: Just to clarify again, nobody is suggesting that SE would do this, the question is about whether coding Q&A is better suited to existing inside a not-for-profit structure rather than in a commercial entity.  The existing SO data is open-source I believe.

Comment: Uhh, why has this been re-opened? It's basically "Should a coding Q&A site that's not Stack Overflow be run as a non-profit" which is not even remotely on-topic here!

Comment: Re *"to me Stack Overflow ... has literally been life changing"*: We *need* the positive stories, not just [the negative](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-zEUl2UmJo&t=4m52s) [ones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOFUiuJTZSs&t=20s). Thanks for reminding us all. Can someone forward this question to the appropriate SE staff (that may not see it otherwise)?

Answer (score 12):

Should it? Maybe.

Will it? Never.

SO is SE's clicks machine. It's what brings visitors to SE's other products. It's what makes Teams tick, and the ads are a significant source of SE's income.

There's no corporate incentive to SE to make SO a nonprofit. They've got nothing to gain from it.

The comments on your question also mention the fact that investors wouldn't be very happy with a change like that.

Comment: Reminder: Investors are owners of a company. "Investors wouldn't be happy" = "owners wouldn't be happy" = "you get fired for even thinking about it." I mention this because the way the last sentence is worded makes it sound like investors are just a small thing. When you get funding, you *literally sell the company*.

Comment: That was kindof the joke with that line. Downplaying the significance of investors.

Comment: @user253751 Only for a thought you probably won't be fired; firing someone and teaching a new employee for his tasks has a cost. But it is surely a for-fire motivation for the "higher levels".

Answer (score -2):

Who pays for the infrastructure that makes this site blazing fast (and thus useful)?

Who pays for the support teams when that infrastructure shows signs of instability?

Who handles support tickets for users who decide they no longer wish to participate here (and have upvoted a *ton* of content)?

How do the venture capitalists get the gains back from investing in this industry?

Having cash/profit/liquidity to address those concerns is *vital*.  I assure you that there's no one who would agree to a paywall on Stack Overflow just to keep the lights on, since there's so much *more* that has to happen besides that.

Comment: That's kind of my point; software is essential to the future of the world in so many ways.  Making development of software quicker/cheaper/better is therefore vital, so funding this type of NFP should be a natural fit for many of the existing foundations and also for governments.  It's like teaching people to read, or providing them with encyclopedias, it benefits the whole planet ultimately, so it's a natural fit for charitable donation and charitable contributions of time for members of its community.

Comment: @tomRedox: And therein belies some extreme naivety.  I am firmly unconvinced that any entity would be *that* benevolent and just *give* this site the money it needs to run and function and remain healthy.  You see the value in the site the same I do.  However, I also see the cost to this value and I'm not so convinced that anyone is gonna just fill the void at the snap of some fingers if this decided to turn non-profit/non-stock.

Comment: If a government gets involved in funding SO @tomRedox, let's just hope it's a nice govt, not a protectionist one that may decide to put a "wall" around SO to keep other countries out of it..... I mean, I definitely see some people who would do that if they got their hands on the site. So I'm not convinced Govt entities are the best idea here necessarily :/.

Comment: I don't think any of these points is an impossible obstacle... Wikipedia surely tackles the first two problems you cite, plus probably some form of the third, yet they manage to keep it running, reasonably fast and without ads, all through donations and voluntary work. Conceptually, a nonprofit SO/SE (meant as Q&A sites, not as their current parent company) doesn't look impossible to me. Of course that would be a new project handled by an entity that is not SE Inc, possibly starting importing the current corpus of SO/SE questions and answers.

Comment: @MatteoItalia:  Wikipedia is *very* straightforward to curate.  Facts are facts, and there is no "ranking"; there are references to find, references to add, and trolls/griefers to deal with.  The overhead turns out to be fairly low, too - the system has to be performant but doesn't have to update its state too dynamically. A Q&A site is ***not*** linear in that same capacity, and a site like Stack Overflow has a ton of additional features/functionality bolted on to it.  It's not *impossible*, no.  But it doesn't make much sense to give it away for free, either.